# Cannot connect to apple id using Virtual Box Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, macos-high-sierra

When I try connecting to the app store, itunes, etc. it returns an error that says "Unexpected error occured". That's it, nothing else.

I have a virtual machine running Mac OS High Sierra. I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager. I have given my mac environment a "serial number" using **VBoxManage setextradata “MacOS High Sierra” VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial "number"** When I go to Apple>About this Mac it lists the correct serial number I assigned it too. Before hand, it would just list the serial number as 0.

My question is, how do I connect my mac environment to my apple id for app store, itunes, etc?

Comment: StackOverFlow is Q&A website for programmers ,you can post your question on (https://superuser.com)

Answer (score 2):

I changed the DNS to apples DNS

system prefs>network>advanced

Click + on the DNS entries and add 8.8.4.4

Make sure the ethernet remains green. save. Then reconnect to the appleID. It will still take a little longer to log in but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the Keychain did the trick for me.

Keychain Access -> Preferences -> Reset default keychains

Then it takes a minute to log in, but does so eventually.

Answer (score 0):

It took me ages, but I finally got my VM with MacOS working. I suggest really to use VMWare. I was stubborn and tried to use Virtualbox but I got no luck at all.

With VMWare I got it fully functional.

I used this code first answer and no errors!
[ICLOUD_UNSUPPORTED_DEVICE when installing macOS Big Sur in VMware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186036/icloud-unsupported-device-when-installing-macos-big-sur-in-vmware)

Here is a link to use clover on VMware
https://github.com/toshmatik/VMWare-iMessage/blob/master/instructions.md