# ICLOUD_UNSUPPORTED_DEVICE when installing macOS Big Sur in VMware

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, apple-id

When I try to install macOS in VMware Workstation I get a popup error when I try to login with my Apple ID:

```
ICLOUD_UNSUPPORTED_DEVICE
```

That's all it says.

How do I make my VM appear as an iCloud supported device?

Answer (score 12):

Shut down the VM gracefully, then add the following to the end of your virtual machine's `.vmx` file to make VMware believe it is running on Mac hardware:

```
board-id = "Mac-551B86E5744E2388"
hw.model.reflectHost = "FALSE"
hw.model = "MacBookPro14,3"
serialNumber.reflectHost = "FALSE"
serialNumber = "C02XXXXXX153"
smbios.reflectHost = "FALSE"
efi.nvram.var.ROM.reflectHost = "FALSE"
efi.nvram.var.MLB.reflectHost = "FALSE"
efi.nvram.var.ROM = "3c0754a2f9be"
```

Boot the VM.

Open iTunes, click `Account` menu, then `Sign In`.

[Source for the above lines](https://www.wikigain.com/fix-macos-mojave-imessage-icloud-app-store-vmware/)

Comment: I want to add that MOBILEME_CREATE_UNAVAILABLE_MAC may be thrown when trying to connect. To avoid that, you should copy informations like described in the given link with Clover Configurator.

Answer (score 1):

In case of MOBILEME_CREATE_UNAVAILABLE_MAC

- change hw.model to "MacBookPro18,3" for example
- change serialNumber, replace all X to random numbers
- try add board-id.reflectHost = "FALSE"